# tikz: wires not connecting up to the nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I don't know why the wires are not connecting upto the nodes (a) and (b). Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]
    % The two gates
    \node[xor gate, inputs={nn}] (xor) at (0,1) {};
    \node[and gate, inputs={nn}] (and) at (0,0) {};

    % XOR input wires
    \draw (xor.input 1) --++(left:1cm);
    \draw (xor.input 2) --++(left:1cm);

    % Drawing the nodes to be connected with the AND gate inputs
    \draw (xor.input 1) node[left=4mm](a) {};
    \draw[fill] (a) circle (0.02);
    \draw (xor.input 2) node[left=7mm](b) {};
    \draw[fill] (b) circle (0.02);

    \draw (and.input 1) -| (a);
    \draw (and.input 2) -| (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `coordinate` or `inner sep=0pt` for nodes

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try to define a and b as coordinates.

Comment: Thank you so much. `inner sep=0pt` helped.